# How to group items from array that match, into another array?

Tags: arrays, swift

For example say I have an array like so:

`var someArray = ["1", "1", "2"]`

I need to put this into two arrays that look like:

`["1","1"]`

`["2"]`

How can I go about this?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Dictionary initializer **[init(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919592-init)**
Then just get arrays by accessing *values* property.

Example:

```
let dic = Dictionary(grouping: someArray) { $0 }
let values = Array(dic.values)
print(values)
```

Result:

```
[["2"], ["1", "1"]]
```

Comment: This is the best way. He's using O(N) runtime complexity to match the objects compared to @Bruno 's implementation which uses O(N*N)

Comment: @kirander remove `.first!`. If he's working with `Strings`, `first` would group numbers like `"1"` and `"12"` together

Comment: My initial down vote was due to it being a link only post. Now this is definitely my favourite method :D

Comment: on the first line, i get an error `Generic parameter 'key' could not be inferred`

Comment: Show us how you declared the array

Comment: `let someArray: [String] = ["1","3","4","1"]`

Comment: Hmm.. are you using swift 2 or 3 ?

Comment: it is available from Xcode 9. You need to upgrade it. Anyway it is needed to develop for iOS 11 and iPhone X.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some facts (the upvote and answer should go to @kirander)

With @kirander method's is using the `Dictionary` to map the objects in a `O(N) runtime` and `O(N) memory`.

The other solutions are mostly running in `O(N*N) runtime` and `O(N) memory`. Because of this, grouping a random array of **1000** items will take: **0.07s** with @kirander solution and **34s**. with other solutions.

```
func benchmark(_ title:String, code: ()->()) {
  let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
  code()
  let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
  print("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s.")
}

var array:[String] = []
for _ in 0...1000 {
  array.append("\(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))")
}

// @kirander solution 0.07s
benchmark("Dictionary", code: {

  let dic = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: { $0 })
  let values = Array(dic.values)
})


// @Bruno solution ~34s
benchmark("Array", code: {
  var resultingArrays = [[String]]()
  for value in array {
    let ar = array.filter({ $0 == value })
    if !resultingArrays.contains(where: {$0 == ar}) {
      resultingArrays.append(ar)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Interesting to see how the solutions scale. Thank you for that!

Comment: I'm getting an compile time error `Generic parameter 'key' could not be inferred` for @kirander solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var someArray = ["1", "1", "2"]

var resultingArrays = [[String]]()

for value in someArray {
    let array = someArray.filter({ $0 == value })
    if !resultingArrays.contains(where: {$0 == array}) {
        resultingArrays.append(array)
    }
}
```

Comment: @kirander's comment was edited. Now I agree that his answer is the more efficient and better one.

Comment: @RobertD.Mogos Its my opinion you may have different opinion. Because when i commented on this answer that time no one given proper answer. So according to me it is best answer.